# SQL search displaying to much data

Tags: sql

Whenever i use a SQL command that searches more than a single table i get the output repeating all the data in a table a few times.

When i use the command

```
SELECT  `INSPECTOR`.`name` 
FROM  `INSPECTION` ,  `INSPECTOR` 
WHERE  `inspectDate` =  '2013-04-15'
```

My output is

```
name
Erik Welch
Esmail Dickens
Parker Armistead
Sherif Quinones
Kennard Moors
Duke Kevinson
Frederick Curtis
Abbas Hawking
Natanael Moulin
Erik Welch
Esmail Dickens
Parker Armistead
Sherif Quinones
Kennard Moors
Duke Kevinson
Frederick Curtis
Abbas Hawking
Natanael Moulin
Erik Welch
Esmail Dickens
Parker Armistead
Sherif Quinones
Kennard Moors
Duke Kevinson
Frederick Curtis
Abbas Hawking
Natanael Moulin
Erik Welch
Esmail Dickens
Parker Armistead
```

I should get

```
Erik Welch
Parker Armistead
Natanael Moulin
```

The INSPECTOR table is

```
inspectorNum   name                salary    hireDate
461861         Erik Welch          32000     2010-03-24
575328         Esmail Dickens      45000     2011-10-07
845427         Parker Armistead    36000     2010-01-14
157114         Sherif Quinones     35000     2009-05-14
492680         Kennard Moors       45000     2009-04-09
492680         Duke Kevinson       38000     2007-03-15
360931         Frederick Curtis    33000     2009-10-17
355677         Abbas Hawking       41000     2010-02-20
105270         Natanael Moulin     56000     2006-09-20
```

The INSPECTION table

```
inspectorNum   applianceNum   inspectDate   score
575328         99960369       2013-07-07    7
492680         99968531       2013-04-30    5
461861         99992394       2013-04-15    7
461861         99992394       2013-04-15    7
845427         77776499       2013-04-15    7
105270         99992394       2013-04-15    8
575328         77728816       2013-03-22    8
157114         77754539       2013-03-22    8
461861         88894054       2013-03-22    6
```

Comment: Whenever asking SQL questions tag your DBMS. A query in MySQL can look different from the same query in SQL Server for instance, because SQL dialects differ and one DBMS may offer things another doesn't feature. So what DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You are only filtering the inspection table in your where clause.

You must specify a join between the two in order to filter both.

Answer (score 1):

Always use join where you have to get data from more than 1 tables,

```
SELECT distinct INSPECTOR.name
FROM  INSPECTION as inspection
inner join INSPECTOR as inspector
on inspector.inspectorNum = inspection.inspectorNum
WHERE inspection.inspectDate =  '2013-04-15'
```

Comment: Here the data (`name`) is got from *one* table (`inspector`) only. So your advice doesn't seem appropriate for the task given. Because of joining the two tables your query would return 'Erik Welch' twice, because he had two inspections that day, but the OP just wants it once it seems.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : thanks i have updated my query as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  INSPECTOR.name
FROM  INSPECTION inspn inner join  INSPECTOR insr
ON  insr.inspectorNum = inspn.inspectorNum
AND inspn.inspectDate =  '2013-04-15'
```

Comment: join condition is missing :(

Answer (score 0):

You are using a join syntax that was out-dated more than 20 years ago. The comma in your query would nowadays be replaced by `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT  inspector.name 
FROM inspection CROSS JOIN inspector
WHERE  inspectDate =  '2013-04-15';
```

And this would show what you are actually doing: cross join the tables, i.e. combine *every* record in one table with *every* record in the other.

Had you used proper explicit join syntax, you wouldn't have written a `CROSS JOIN` but an `INNER JOIN` (or simply `JOIN`):

```
SELECT  inspector.name 
FROM inspection JOIN inspector
WHERE  inspectDate =  '2013-04-15';
```

and the DBMS would have told you that you forgot to tell it *how* to join the two tables (i.e. by what criteria find record matches), because an inner join needs an `ON` clause to tell it that:

```
SELECT inspector.name 
FROM inspection 
JOIN inspector ON inspector.inspectornum = inspection.inspectornum
WHERE inspection.inspectDate =  '2013-04-15';
```

As to the query in general: This would still give you inspectors multifold when they had more than one inspection that day. (You could remove duplicates from your results, however, by using `DISTINCT`). But if you only select the inspectors names, why do you join the tables at all? Are you trying to only show inspectors that made an inspection that day? Then use `EXISTS` or `IN`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM inspector 
WHERE inspectornum IN
(
  SELECT inspectornum
  FROM inspection
  WHERE inspectDate = '2013-04-15'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Inner Join` on 'inspectorNum'

`SELECT 
    T2.name 
FROM 
    INSPECTION AS T1
    INNER JOIN INSPECTOR AS T2 ON T1.inspectorNum = T2.inspectorNum
WHERE
    T1.inspectDate =  '2013-04-15'`